# How can I modify a method's behaviour for testing purposes?

Tags: python, class, methods, mocking, monkeypatching

```
# file: cisco_driver.py

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, run_commands):
        self.run_commands = run_commands

    def myFunction(self, interface_name):
        command = f"show interface status {interface_name}"
        output = self.run_commands(command)
        return output
```

1. The function `myFunction` takes an interface name as input, for example: `myFunction("Gig1/1/1")`
2. It then generated a command, in this case: `show interface status Gig1/1/1`
3. It then uses `run_commands` to SSH into a device, execute the command, and retrieve its output

For the purpose of pytest testing, I want to test the **command that is being generated**, and **not** the execution of this command. I want to bypass `run_commands` and return the command itself, not the output of it.

How can I accomplish this? Is it possible? Can I mock this? Monkeypatch?

I want it to behave like this:

```
    def myFunction(interface_name):
        command = f"show interface status {interface_name}"
        return command
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to *focus* the question on a specific problem. "Can I mock this? Monkeypatch?" Well, do you know any techniques for doing so? Did you try them? If you tried them, what happened when you tried them, and how did it fail to solve the problem? If you don't know any techniques, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [find some](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pytest+mock+monkeypatch)? What exactly do you actually need help with, and why?

Comment: If you don't want to test the function `myFunction` as it is currently written, why don't you simply write the function that you actually want to test?  This has to be far, far simpler than any of the solutions you are considering.  In fact, you've already written that function - it's right at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it and was able to find a solution:

```py
# pytest_file
def test_case():

    # Initialize new instance of class
    # Use None since "run_commands" will be bypassed
    new_instance = myClass(None)

    # New function that will replace the existing run_commands function
    def mock_run_commands(command)
        # Original behavior of run_commands is to create an SSH connection
        # Instead, I want it to return the same command
        return command

    # Redefine run_commands to my customized function
    new_instance.run_commands = mock_run_commands

    # Pass param through class method
    # This will return "show interface status Gig1/1/1"
    selected_command = new_instance.myFunction("Gig1/1/1")

    # Compare the command produced by class method with what expected outcome
    assert selected_command == expected_command
```